# When is $T+T^*$ is unbounded, given that $T$ is closed and densely defineD?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I do know that if $T$ is closed and densely defined, then $T+T^*$ could be trivially bounded. For example, $T+T^*$ could be defined on $\{0\}$ only, or e.g. when $T^*=-T$ then $T+T^*$ is bounded.

I would like to know if anyone is aware of any paper or result which gives conditions that guarantee that $T+T^*$ be unbounded?

Thanks for your help.

Hichem

PS **I also know that $T+T^*$ and $T-T^*$ cannot be bounded simultaneously.**

Comment: You phrased your question so one could correctly answer merely "Yes".  or "Yes, I'm aware of such a paper."

Comment: Suggestion: your first two sentences are good.  But ask users you'd "like to know if anyone knows of a paper or result ...", and what motivates your question.  That will help users better answer your question.

Comment: I believe that you have in mind an interesting math problem, but you should do a better job of presenting it.  The body of the Question should be reasonably self-contained, telling Readers what kind of things $T$ and $T*$ are (for example).  It seems you have in mind that $T$ is itself unbounded, but you don't state that (and it is seemingly an important aspect of the problem setup).

Comment: @hardmath
Yes, you are right. It is strongly related to the conjecture 2.9 in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.09893.pdf

Comment: So wouldn't it be easy for you to include the problem setup (e.g. that $T$ and $T^*$ are an operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$ and its adjoint) in the body of your Question?  A link to your paper is useful, but putting all the context together with a self-contained problem statement in the body of your Question is the best practice.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Thanks for your comment.